# How to get rid of remnants of a user profile in /var/folders?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, user-account

I created a user, TestUser1, via System Preferences > Users and Groups on 22 April 2021, deleted it, didn't let it create a backup (since it was a test profile), but I noticed in /var/folders possible remnants of it.

This is on Catalina 10.15.7, 2020 Macbook Pro.

Would disabling SIP temporarily and/or sudo'ing to remove the files be a way to get rid of this?

I'm not sure what to do about this, and how to, in future, deal with remnants of user accounts created.

Comment: Can you describe the "possible remnants" in more detail? I'd be surprised if they were compromising in any way.
Files in /var are usually cleared on restart. Have you done that?

Comment: @benwiggy; The possible remnants is a folder called "_j2" in /var/folders. I have restarted it, and it's within /private/var/folders, with the date created/modified as 22 April 2021. They're not compromising, the remnants are just the folder described.

Comment: You mean it's just a folder with the name of the old user account, but no actual data? You could try a Safe Boot restart, which does clear a bit more. The other option might be to boot to Recovery, and in Terminal there mount the disk and delete stuff (and then you're already in position to disable and re-enable SIP , if needs be.)

Answer (score 1):

**"I'm not sure what to do about this"**

My overwhelming instinct is to leave it alone. There's no personal data there, and it's not taking up significant space. The OS will probably tidy it up at some point.
There's a very very tiny possibility that the OS may actually need these files for something and get confused if they're not there.

Yes, you probably could find a way to delete the files manually; -- or you could do something useful with your time instead! IMO, the less maintenance I have to do, the better.